# Why did my Nikon J1 stop working in all except smart photo mode?

Tags: nikon

My Nikon J1, which has had the 10-30 lens fix, has stopped working in all except the smart photo mode.  When I try to use any other mode, the camera shuts itself off.  Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Are you sure the battery's good?

Answer (score 2):

You can send it to Nikon for a repair estimate. This can be economical depending on the fault.

The 10-30 had a fairly common fault mode which resulted in an all black image - I had one repaired for free by Nikon. Your fault seems unrelated but it might be worth getting Nikon to look at it.